# What does integral of vector fields mean in a general smooth manifold?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

For simplicity, let everything be smooth and consider the differential equation
$$
\dot{x} (t)=A(t) x(t)
$$
Then for every initial condition $x_0$, there exists a unique solution $\gamma_t (x_0)$. It's not hard to see that $\gamma_t :\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ is a diffeomorphism/linear map with $(\gamma_t)^{-1}=\gamma_{-t}$. Now let us consider the ODE
$$
\dot{y}(t)=A(t)y(t)+b(t)
$$
Then it's easy to check that the unique solution with initial condition $y_0$ is given by
$$
y(t)=\gamma_t\left(y_0 +\int_0^t(\gamma_s)^{-1}(b_s)ds \right)
$$
Indeed, if you regard $b(t)$ as a vector field with the natural isomorphism, then
$$
\nabla\gamma_t\cdot(\gamma_t)^{-1}(b_t)=d\gamma_t\circ d\gamma_{-t} (b_t)=b_t
$$

**Question**. Now what if I want to generalize this formula to a general smooth manifold? What would the integral of
$$
\int_0^t (\gamma_s)^{-1}b_sds
$$
mean in this context?

Comment: If you want to generalize to an arbitrary manifold, you run into problems before you get to the integral: What would the differential equation look like? Neither of the terms on the right side would make sense, since there is no notion of a linear map $A$ or a position-independent vector $b$.

Comment: @Kajelad I see. That makes sense